# How to handle web element(enable button) having same Xpath?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2, xpath

I am working on a web page which having 3 web elements with 3 enable buttons and all buttons having same Xpath.so my need is to click on the button A and print the title of the webelement on every login and logout operation.

Comment: It is not possible for two elements to share the same Xpath.

Comment: Refer my answer in this link `https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26436/how-to-handle-if-xpath-is-same-for-multiple-drop-down/26439#26439`

Comment: Can you add the DOM screen of your application for this scenario?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, How I worked on this same scenario:
Suppose if you have 3 buttons with the same XPath-like in my DOM:

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Edit"/>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Edit"/>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Edit"/>
```

The best option to overcome this situation is:

> **1. By XPath indexing option:**

```
By.xpath("(//input[@type='submit'])[0]")  ---> To Click 1st Button
By.xpath("(//input[@type='submit'])[1]")  ---> To Click 2nd Button
By.xpath("(//input[@type='submit'])[2]")  ---> To Click 3rd Button
```

OR

```
XPath = "//input[@id='button' and @value='Edit'][0]
XPath = "//input[@id='button' and @value='Edit'][1]
XPath = "//input[@id='button' and @value='Edit'][2]
```

> **2. BY generating *Absolute XPath* from starting Node to Descent Node:**

```
html/body/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input[0]
html/body/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input[1]
html/body/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input[2]
```

> **3. Use of List web elements:**

```
    String cssSelectorOfBtn="input[type='submit'][id='button']"; 
 //****Add cssSelector of your 1st webelement

    List<WebElement> button =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorOfBtn));
    button.get(0).click();
    button.get(1).click();
    button.get(2).click();
```

Let me know if it works...

Comment: The result gave a IndexOutOfBoundException actually doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @rabiacatak If you're having a problem, try to isolate it and, if necessary, ask a new question. Thanks!